# Последовательное появление элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

Есть список меню на главной странице сайта.
Подскажите как реализовать последовательное появление элементов при загрузке страницы.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

ul.menu {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

ul.menu li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: tomato;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>About us</li>
      <li>Services</li>
      <li>Team</li>
      <li>Portfolio</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать `delay()` в цикле для каждого пункта.

```js
var items = $('ul.menu li');
items.css('opacity', 0);
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  $(items[i]).delay(i * 400).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 400);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

ul.menu {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

ul.menu li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: tomato;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>About us</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Team</li>
  <li>Portfolio</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Идея то что нужно, но у меня фиксированная высота и код выполняется с низу вверх :\

Comment: @kovanov, не понял как высота влияет на очередность

Comment: вот такая история получается https://1229440.mydent.web.hosting-test.net/  , а хотелось бы чтобы меню появлялось снизу вверх.

Comment: Тогда надо их не прятать сразу, а делать прозрачными - `items.hide();` заменить на `items.css('opacity', 0);`, Изменил ответ

Comment: Работает! Спасибище )))